# WKInterfaceSwitch switchAction(value: Bool) value is always false Apple Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit

I'm currently developing an Apple Watch App. 
I used WKInterfaceSwitch to toggle the state of something.

In my WKIntefaceController I connected the action that is called when the switch is toggled.

```
@IBAction func switchAction(value: Bool) {
    NSLog("\(value)")
}
```

When I run the project in the simulator the console output obviously is:

```
2015-05-28 20:42:08.067 Watch Test WatchKit Extension[1503:28272] false
2015-05-28 20:42:08.896 Watch Test WatchKit Extension[1503:28272] true
2015-05-28 20:42:10.547 Watch Test WatchKit Extension[1503:28272] false
2015-05-28 20:42:11.558 Watch Test WatchKit Extension[1503:28272] true
```

When I run the project on the physical watch the console will display this:

```
2015-05-28 20:44:06.044 Watch Test WatchKit Extension[345:16118] false
2015-05-28 20:44:06.954 Watch Test WatchKit Extension[345:16118] false
2015-05-28 20:44:07.318 Watch Test WatchKit Extension[345:16118] false
2015-05-28 20:44:08.343 Watch Test WatchKit Extension[345:16118] false
```

Does anyone know why this happens.

A full project that shows the issue can be downloaded here:

https://bitbucket.org/rcpfuchs/watch-kit-wkinterfaceswitch-issue

---

This seems to happen on some devices only, so if you are developing an Apple Watch app better track the state as follows:

```
var switchValue = false // the value you chose in storyboard
@IBAction func switchAction(value: Bool) {
// ignore value
    switchValue = !switchValue
// do something with switchValue
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem!

Perhaps of interest: I'm seeing this happen only on one watch, paired with an iPhone 5s.

I'm not seeing the same problem with a different Watch paired with an iPhone 6. The problem also doesn't show on the Simulator.

Both watches have version 1.01, and both phones have iOS 8.3

I could not find a direct fix, as it looks like some sort of bug in WatchKit. However, the work-around is pretty easy.

I set a Boolean member variable, to record the initial switch state. Then, when the callback comes-in, I invert the state of the member variable, and use that rather than the value passed by WatchKit (which I now ignore!).

I hope this helps! If you find any more, or happen to spot that this is fixed by Apple, do please share that information here!

NB: I've filed this as a bug with Apple, as radar 21171938

Pete

Comment: Hey I use iPhone5 with a 38mm black Watch, don't know which model exacly since it is not mine. Tracking the state by observing the changes and an initial know state seems to be the way to go. I also did this in my project. Nevertheless it is pretty dangerous if you do not have this problem. A guy I know tested it with his watch and did not have it. I will accept your answer since it has a workaround. - Simon

Comment: Simon: I couldn't agree more, this is a really nasty bug that could catch-out a lot of Apple Watch developers. I'm very happy that my work-around helped you. Thank goodness for stackoverflow!! Pete